# Why can the current in this region be represented as this formula?$I_{in}=I-I\frac{r^2-b^2}{c^2-b^2}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

An air coaxial transmission line has a solid inner conductor of radius a and an outer conductor of inner radius b and outer radius c. Find $\vec B$ as a functions of radial distance r.

[image]

The region in $b<r<c$:
$I_{in}=I-I\frac{r^2-b^2}{c^2-b^2}=I\frac{c^2-r^2}{c^2-b^2},$so the $\vec {B}=\vec u_\phi \frac{\mu_0}{2\pi r}I\frac{c^2-r^2}{c^2-b^2}$

I don't understand why the $I_{in}$ can be written as $ I-I\frac{r^2-b^2}{c^2-b^2}$,can anyone teach me why? this question has been bothering me for a long time

Comment: According to your formula, $I_{in}=\tfrac{c^2-r^2}{ c^2-b^2}$, immediately under the diagram, $I_{in}$ is the current in the shell of the outer conductor bounded by cylinders of radii $r$ and $c$. Is this what you intend? What else do you mean by $I_{in}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current passing through a circle of radius $r$ can be broken down into two constituents:  a positive current $I$ from the central conductor, and a negative current from the outer conductor.

Assuming that the current is uniformly distributed in the outer conductor, the magnitude of the negative current is equal to $-I$ times the fraction of its cross-sectional area included in the circle of radius $r$.

The circle of radius $r$ encloses an annulus of inner radius $b$ and outer radius $r$, so its area is $\pi(r^2 - b^2)$.  By similar logic, the total cross-sectional area of the outer conductor is $\pi(c^2 - b^2)$.  Thus, the fraction of the area enclosed is $(r^2 - b^2)/(c^2 - b^2)$.

Combine all of these facts and you will get the equation you're confused about.